# Matplotlib Pandas: visualization of 3 columns (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have parsed data and created a small data frame that looks like this:

| Region | State or Province | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Central | Illinois | 98971.25 |
| East | New York | 223930.48 |
| South | Florida | 87651.11 |
| West | California | 288310.61 |

And I want my graph to look like this:

[image: graph]

Let me know if this is possible to be done and if it is not, give me some suggestions on what do you think best representation of this data would be!

And when I try running the basic bar chart it gives me an error

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
p = max_sales_by_state["State or Province"]
s = max_sales_by_state["Sales"]

plt.bar(p, s, color =['maroon', 'aqua', 'magenta', 'green'])
 
plt.xlabel("State / Province")
plt.ylabel("Sales")
plt.title("Sales per state")
plt.show()
```

I get an error KeyError: 'State or Province'

Comment: Would a legend with the names(Illinois, ...) also be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that is an option, if this version is not possible, Do you maybe have an idea of better representation?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data={
        'Region':['Central', 'East', 'South', 'West'],
        'States':['Illinois', 'New York', 'Florida', 'California'],
        'Sales':[98971.25, 223930.48, 87651.11, 288310.61],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values('Sales', ascending=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['Region'], df['Sales'], label=df['States'], color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'grey'])
for bar, state in zip(ax.patches, df['States']):
    ax.text(bar.get_x()+bar.get_width()/2, 10000, state, rotation=90, color = 'black', ha = 'center', va = 'bottom')
```

resulting in :

[image]

You might want to play around with coloring and font properties

Comment: Its giving me an error KeyError: 'Region',  im not sure why is it not letting me access a single column. This shall definitely be working

Comment: The  thing is i didnt have an index column, so it was setting a 'Region' as an index and it didn't recognise it.